# How to create a dynamic array that can hold different objects all derived from the same base class in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, dynamic

I have an assignment that doesn't allow me to use the vector class. I have a base class called Shape and different derived class such as Rectangle and Circle and i have to create my own vector class that has a dynamic array which can hold all these different shapes. I have used the following method that seems to work well

```
 int **shape=new int*[capacity];
```

My problem comes with the "add_shape" function. I know how to add a shape individually using for example:

```
shape[0]=new Rectangle();
shape[1]=new Circle();
```

But how would one go about creating a universal function for adding a shape that could either be a rectangle or circle for instance.

Comment: `MyVector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>>`?

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to elaborate on Nicky C's comment.

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Shape {};
class Rectangle : public Shape {};
class Circle : public Shape {};
template <class Type> class MyVector {}; // implement (with push method, etc.)

int main()
{
    MyVector<unique_ptr<Shape>> v;
    v.push(unique_ptr<Shape>(new Rectangle()));
    v.push(unique_ptr<Shape>(new Circle()));

    return 0;
}
```

The vector contains elements of type `unique_ptr<Shape>` which is the base class. Each element of the vector can be `unique_ptr<Rectangle>` or `unique_ptr<Circle>` as well. However, if the vector were of type `unique_ptr<Rectangle>`, each element would have to be of type `unique_ptr<Rectangle>` (i.e. it could not be of type `unique_ptr<Circle>`).

Since you are allocating memory on the heap, using `unique_ptr` just makes sure that you don't need to call `delete` yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One of the strengths of inheritance/polymorphism is that you can use a derived class wherever a base class is needed.  It is an important key concept.  For instance, as in your code above, you can do:

```
Shape *s = new Shape();
s = new Rectangle();
s = new Circle();
```

This also applies to function parameters:

```
class DynamicArray
{
   private:
      Shape **_shapes[];
   ...
   public:
      void add_shape(Shape *s)
      {
         // Add the shape to _shapes;
      }
   ...
};

void main()
{
   DynamicArray array;
   array.add_shape(new Shape()):
   array.add_shape(new Rectangle()):
   array.add_shape(new Circle()):
}
```